# def macro inside case statement

Tags: scala, macros

I'd like to ask where def macros can be called and when they are expanded? I guess we cant just put an appropriate generated AST anywhere it fits?
For example, I want this:

```
(2,1) match { 
    case StandaloneMacros.permutations(1,2) => true ; 
    case (_,_) => false 
}
```

become this after macro expansion

```
(2,1) match { 
    case (1,2) | (2,1) => true ; 
    case (_,_) => false 
}
```

My macro *permutations* produces an Alternative of tuples. But when I run the first snippet, I get

```
macro method permutations is not a case class, nor does it have an unapply/unapplySeq member
```

I also tried defining a *Permutations* object with unapply macro method but got another error:

```
scala.reflect.internal.FatalError: unexpected tree: class scala.reflect.internal.Trees$Alternative
```

So: Is it possible to achieve at all?

Comment: See [extractor macros](http://docs.scala-lang.org/overviews/macros/extractors.html)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I came up with a solution some time ago, and I thought I'd share it with you.
To achieve above task I've used a Transformer and transformCaseDefs

```
object Matcher {

  def apply[A, B](expr: A)(patterns: PartialFunction[A, B]): B = macro apply_impl[A,B]

  def apply_impl[A: c.WeakTypeTag, B: c.WeakTypeTag](c: Context)(expr: c.Expr[A])(patterns: c.Expr[PartialFunction[A, B]]): c.Expr[B] = {
    import c.universe._

    def allElemsAreLiterals(l: List[Tree]) = l forall {
      case Literal(_) | Ident(_) => true
      case _ => throw new Exception("this type of pattern is not supported")
    }

    val transformer = new Transformer {
      override def transformCaseDefs(trees: List[CaseDef]) = trees.map {
        case cas @ CaseDef(pat @ Apply(typTree, argList), guard, body) if allElemsAreLiterals(argList) =>

          val permutations = argList.permutations.toList.map(t => q"(..$t)").map {
            case Apply(_, args) => Apply(typTree, args)
          }

          val newPattern = Alternative(permutations)
          CaseDef(newPattern, guard, body)
        case x => x
      }
    }
    c.Expr[B](q"${transformer.transform(patterns.tree)}($expr)")
  }
}
```

It would be shorter, but somehow you need to provide the same TypeTree which was used in original (before transformation) case statement.

This way, it can be used like this

```
val x = (1,2,3)

Matcher(x) {
  case (2,3,1) => true 
  case _ => false
}
```

which is then translated to something like

```
val x = (1,2,3)

x match {
  case (1,2,3) | (1,3,2) | (2,1,3) | (2,3,1) | (3,1,2) | (3,2,1) => true
  case _ => false
}
```